# Unity Dependency Injection only working when injecting into MVC Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

I wish to inject a service into a custom class i have created> i have been using Dependency injection to inject the same service into my WebApi controllers but cannot seem to understand why it doesn't work in my "InputDataValidationModel" class

This is what i am trying to do:

```
 public class InputDataValidationModel
{
    private  ISec300_EE_SubmissionRepository _service { get; set; }

    public InputDataValidationModel(ISec300_EE_SubmissionRepository service)
    {
        _service = service;
    } 
}
```

In the Global.asax i registered the types as follow:

```
   protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        ConfigureApi(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    }

    void ConfigureApi(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var unity = new UnityContainer();

        // Register the Controllers that should be injectable
        unity.RegisterType<SEC300_EE_SubmissionController>();
        unity.RegisterType<InputDataValidationModel>();

        unity.RegisterType<ISec300_EE_SubmissionRepository, Sec300_EE_SubmissionRepository>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        unity.RegisterType<IClientRepository, ClientRepository>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

        // Finally, override the default dependency resolver with Unity
        config.DependencyResolver = new IoCContainer(unity);
    }
```

What I cant understand specifically is that this works perfectly when done in my controller below:

```
public class SEC300_EE_SubmissionController : ApiController
{
    private ISec300_EE_SubmissionRepository _service;      
    public SEC300_EE_SubmissionController(ISec300_EE_SubmissionRepository service)
    {
        if (service == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("service");
        }
        _service = service;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you create instances of your InputDataValidationModel?

Comment: @raderick, The object is populated through json serialization from the FrontEnd, my method accepts an input parameter of type "InputDataValidationModel"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work because controllers are instantiated by `Web API`, and when Web API  creates a controller it calls BeginScope which is the entry point to call your IoC and proceeds to resolve and constructs objects for you.

In your case `InputDataValidationModel` is not used and may be for this reason you don't have the instance

## update

*`Do you perhaps have any suggestions on how i would inject my service into InputDataValidationModel ?`*

**Option 1**

You can use `IDependencyResolver` take a look at this  [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection)  Dependency Resolution with the Unity Container`'

And after this you can resolve your service like this

```
var instance =GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof (InputDataValidationModel));
```

**Option 2**
You might use service locator even it is an anti-pattern

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{            
    UnityServiceLocator locator = new UnityServiceLocator(ConfigureUnityContainer(
    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => locator);
 
    var a = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IFoo>();
    var b = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IFoo>();
 
    Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(b));            
}
 
private static IUnityContainer ConfigureUnityContainer()
{
    UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
    container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    return container;
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thank you for the response, do you perhaps have any suggestions on how i would inject my service into InputDataValidationModel ?

Comment: Thank you very much